# No disk space available, assertion error and permission denied

Tags: permissions, gparted, fdisk

I tried to install Ubuntu with my windows 8.1 but the installer is showing no disk space available..
[The above error](https://i.stack.imgur.com/af2AN.png)

I tried to open gparted it showed an assertion error.. Someone please help

I have a **50 GB unallocated** space kept for installation shrinked from C Drive

This is the assertion error:
Assertion (metadata_length > 0) at ../../../libparted/labels/dos.c:2313 in function add_logical_part_metadata() failed.

This is when I run `sudo fdisk -l`

> Disk /dev/loop0: 1.9 GiB, 1987817472 bytes, 3882456 sectors
>   Units: sectors of 1 * 512 = 512 bytes
>   Sector size (logical/physical): 512 bytes / 512 bytes
>   I/O size (minimum/optimal): 512 bytes / 512 bytes
>
> Disk /dev/loop1: 88.5 MiB, 92778496 bytes, 181208 sectors
>   Units: sectors of 1 * 512 = 512 bytes
>   Sector size (logical/physical): 512 bytes / 512 bytes
>   I/O size (minimum/optimal): 512 bytes / 512 bytes
>
> Disk /dev/loop2: 54.4 MiB, 57069568 bytes, 111464 sectors
>   Units: sectors of 1 * 512 = 512 bytes
>   Sector size (logical/physical): 512 bytes / 512 bytes
>   I/O size (minimum/optimal): 512 bytes / 512 bytes
>
> Disk /dev/loop3: 42.8 MiB, 44879872 bytes, 87656 sectors
>   Units: sectors of 1 * 512 = 512 bytes
>   Sector size (logical/physical): 512 bytes / 512 bytes
>   I/O size (minimum/optimal): 512 bytes / 512 bytes
>
> Disk /dev/loop4: 149.9 MiB, 157184000 bytes, 307000 sectors
>   Units: sectors of 1 * 512 = 512 bytes
>   Sector size (logical/physical): 512 bytes / 512 bytes
>   I/O size (minimum/optimal): 512 bytes / 512 bytes
>
> Disk /dev/loop5: 4 MiB, 4218880 bytes, 8240 sectors
>   Units: sectors of 1 * 512 = 512 bytes
>   Sector size (logical/physical): 512 bytes / 512 bytes
>   I/O size (minimum/optimal): 512 bytes / 512 bytes
>
> Disk /dev/loop6: 14.8 MiB, 15462400 bytes, 30200 sectors
>   Units: sectors of 1 * 512 = 512 bytes
>   Sector size (logical/physical): 512 bytes / 512 bytes
>   I/O size (minimum/optimal): 512 bytes / 512 bytes
>
> Disk /dev/loop7: 1008 KiB, 1032192 bytes, 2016 sectors
>   Units: sectors of 1 * 512 = 512 bytes
>   Sector size (logical/physical): 512 bytes / 512 bytes
>   I/O size (minimum/optimal): 512 bytes / 512 bytes
>
> Disk /dev/sda: 465.8 GiB, 500107862016 bytes, 976773168 sectors
>   Units: sectors of 1 * 512 = 512 bytes
>   Sector size (logical/physical): 512 bytes / 512 bytes
>   I/O size (minimum/optimal): 512 bytes / 512 bytes
>   Disklabel type: dos
>   Disk identifier: 0x2ed72ed6
>
> Device     Boot     Start       End   Sectors   Size Id Type
>   /dev/sda1  *         2048 532617215 532615168   254G  7 HPFS/NTFS/exFAT
>   /dev/sda2       532619010 976771071 444152062 211.8G  f W95 Ext'd (LBA)
>   /dev/sda5       532619073 696337487 163718415  78.1G  7 HPFS/NTFS/exFAT
>   /dev/sda6       696337488 829452014 133114527  63.5G  7 HPFS/NTFS/exFAT
>   /dev/sda7       829452078 976771071 147318994  70.3G  7 HPFS/NTFS/exFAT
>
> Disk /dev/sdb: 7.5 GiB, 8004304896 bytes, 15633408 sectors
>   Units: sectors of 1 * 512 = 512 bytes
>   Sector size (logical/physical): 512 bytes / 512 bytes
>   I/O size (minimum/optimal): 512 bytes / 512 bytes
>   Disklabel type: dos
>   Disk identifier: 0x5092863d
>
> Device     Boot   Start     End Sectors  Size Id Type
>   /dev/sdb1  *          0 4067999 4068000    2G  0 Empty
>   /dev/sdb2       3989132 3994059    4928  2.4M ef EFI (FAT-12/16/32)
>
> Disk /dev/loop8: 3.7 MiB, 3825664 bytes, 7472 sectors
>   Units: sectors of 1 * 512 = 512 bytes
>   Sector size (logical/physical): 512 bytes / 512 bytes
>   I/O size (minimum/optimal): 512 bytes / 512 bytes

Comment: Use `sudo fdisk -l` and for space search `df -h;df -i`

Comment: What type of partition table does your disk use?  If it's DOS/legacy/MBR only four primary partitions can be created, so if having allocated space can only be used to increase the size of an existing partition.  You've not given enough detail to know the cause; `sudo` is needed to elevate privilieges so `fdisk` can work. You also didn't say what release of Ubuntu, and with the 'assertion error' I'd ensure you validated it & your write to install media (https://tutorials.ubuntu.com/tutorial/tutorial-how-to-verify-ubuntu#0 https://help.ubuntu.com/community/Installation/CDIntegrityCheck)

Comment: I use MBR partition there are already 4 partitions now.the 50 GB will be the fifth. It's UBUNTU Desktop 18.04 LTS.

Comment: If all partitions are primary, then you can't create another partition: 4 primary partitions is the limit for MBR systems, even if you still have free (unpartitioned) space. In this case, you'll need to remove the last partition (taking care of saving any data first, if needed), create a extended partition and then logical units inside this extended partition.

Comment: Only the C drive is primary all the others are Logical